# Good online HTML5 tutorials

Tags: html, resources

Are there any good tutorials or resources online for learning HTML5?  I already know HTML I am just looking to learn about the other things in HTML5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you googled there are tons of them http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=html5+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=g1g-s1g4g-m4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: Yes, I have googled but they are all on just a few parts of it, not a complete all-in-one tutorial.

Comment: This one was awesome. I learned a bunch from it: https://learninglineapp.com/courses/8/hmtl5-in-depth

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is my personal favorite: [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)

This one is also good: http://slides.html5rocks.com

The first is purely HTML5, the second wraps HTML5, CSS3, and the new JS API into one presentation, but that's pretty awesome too.

Comment: If I could vote this up 100 times I would! The second one is freaking perfect! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I believe the best link for the api presentation is now at, http://slides.html5rocks.com

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know what you can do with HTML5 and CSS3 you can take a look on [Apple's HTML5 demo](http://www.apple.com/html5).

Answer (score 0):

Along with links given by other you can also have a look into [Technobits.net](http://www.technobits.net), check out following links.

- http://www.technobits.net/technologies/html5-css/
- http://www.technobits.net/search/?q=html5